# when write to the database,database is still empty after registering.how to store data in my database correctly?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing to the Firebase realtime database. How to write to the database correctly?

Where is no errors found. But I changed dependencies of adding the realtime database to the app from `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1` to `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6`.

This is the defined variable

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
```

this is my register activity code part

```
private void register_user (final String displayName, String email, String password){

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uid = current_user.getUid();

                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);

                HashMap<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put("name",displayName);
                userMap.put("status","Hey there I am using ChatApp");
                userMap.put("image","default");
                userMap.put("thumb_image","default");

                mDatabase.setValue(userMap);
            } else {

                mRegProgress.hide();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Couldn't Sign in.Please Check and Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

data entries should store in the database

Comment: after registering my database is still empty.I want to recover that

Comment: The code looks fine. If you don't see any data in the database, make sure the code is actually executed. So put a breakpoint on `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` and run the app in the debugger. Then step through the code and see if each line does/value is what you expect them to do/be. If all of those seem OK, check the logcat output of your app for error messages (for example something related to permissions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default security rules of Firebase Realtime Database rejects read and write. So you need to check and change security rules in firebase console.

Change the security rules into

```
    {
      "rules": {
        "Users": {
           "$uid": {
             ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
             ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
           }
        }
      }
    }
```

For more security options checkout the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)